# Neukirch: Riemann-Roch Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

In the book *Algebraic Number Theory*, Chapter III Riemann Roch Theory, theorem 1.12.

The two fundamental facts of algebraic number theory, the finiteness of the class number and Dirichlets unit theorem, now merge into ($\textbf{and are in fact equivalent}$) the simple statement that the kernel $CH^1(\widehat{\mathcal O})^0$ of the degree map $deg: CH^1(\widehat{\mathcal O})\to \mathbb R$ is 
$\textbf{compact}$.

$\textbf{1.12 Theorem:}$ The group $CH^1(\widehat{\mathcal O})^0$ is compact.

In the proof of the theorem 1.12 prove that:

If $Cl_K(\mathcal O_K)$ is finite and $\mathcal O_K^*$ is finitely generated then $CH^1(\widehat{\mathcal O})^0$ is compact.

$*$ My question is: 
how to prove if $CH^1(\widehat{\mathcal O})^0$ is compact then $Cl_K(\mathcal O_K)$ is finite and $\mathcal O_K^*$ is finitely generated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you looked at the exact seqeuence relating the arakelov chow groups to these two groups? For example, the class group is a quotient by an open subgroup, and so its discrete and compact, so finite.

Comment: I'm confused; in the exact sequence 
$0\to H/\Gamma\to CH^1(\widehat{\mathcal{O}})^0\to CH^1(\mathcal O)\to 0$ the first morpshism is a  (topological) isomorphism in its image? 
Because in the proof the theorem 1.12 Neukirch use that $CH^1(\widehat{\mathcal{O}})^0$ is union of finitely compact cosets of $H/\Gamma$.  Thanks.

Comment: In the proposition 1.11 the exact sequence relating the chow groups use that $\Gamma=\lambda(\mathcal O_K^*)$ is complete lattice but is equivalente that $\mathcal O_K^*$ is finitely generated.

Comment: We have $CH^1(\widehat{\mathcal{O}})^0\approx H/\Gamma \times CH^1(\mathcal O)$ and $H/\Gamma \times CH^1(\mathcal O)$ is compact and $CH^1(\mathcal O)$ is a finite and discrete then $H/\Gamma$ is compact i.e. $\Gamma$ is complete lattice in traze cero space $H$ and this implies that $\mathcal O_K^*$ is finitely generated. Is correct? Thanks,